# Knockout.js: Set a default text if a binding has a given value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'd like to reset the value of an input field (`text=''`) whenever model.id is null.

How to bind the input value to respond to a certain value of an observable object? Something that would look like:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="text: if (model.value == null) { '' }" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `?` operator in data-bind attribute:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: model.id() == null ? 'Default Value' : model.value()" />
```

Comment: Artem, please stop using inline Javascript in the data-bindings when helping people :/

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel, initiate value of the property as follow :

```
var model.value = ko.observable('');
```

In HTML, you don't have to use confitional expression

```
data-bind="text: model.value"
```

Answer (score 0):

check these codes

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: id() == true? 'Value is Red' : value()" />


function viewModel() {
    this.id = ko.observable(true);
    this.value = ko.observable("Value is Green");
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4SKr/

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer should be to create a computed observable to get the label.

```
self.getLabel = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.value() === null ? 'Value is red' : value();
});

<input type="text" data-bind="text: getLabel" />
```